# How to use the selected item of a spinner in an if statement (Android in eclipse)

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, spinner

Hi I have a spinner (spinner5) and whenever the user selects an item that says "age" I want the textview to change to 21. I have tried the following but it doesnt work. I can do this by using `if (getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)` but the spinner's contents are dynamic so thats not an option.

```
            if (spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString()=="age"){
            textArea.setText("21");
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always Use `.equals` when compare two string because `==` only use for `Primitive data types`

`.equals`=compare two string value
`==`     =compare two string refrences

```
if (spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("age")){
            textArea.setText("21");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming that your Item's toString() method is returning "age", then you need to do a string comparison instead of a ==.  In Java, operators can't be overloaded, so == compares the actual object references as opposed to the contents.  What you're looking for is:

```
spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("age")
```

as a rule, always use `.equals()` unless your type is a primitive, like int, float, etc.